# Database Design for similar data across multiple time

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, timestamp

I am attempting to come up with a Database Design that works well for a specific division of my company.

Basically, I have a list of Account Numbers with a ton of fields associated with them. My division needs to compare how these fields change over time (What was in that field for this account number a year ago?).

I am currently thinking of a very linear approach where I use only one large table for the data that is time stamped so a table would have the name AccountInfo04012013 and then the next month would be a new table called AccountInfo05012013. This way we can make comparisons between any two months.

What are the drawbacks of this plan? and what should I be doing instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to have to use timestamps. All database managers will have this built in.